# Фильтр блоков по значениям нескольких выпадающих списков

Tags: javascript

Есть выпадающие списки, которые определяют параметры фильтрации:

```html
<select id="select">
    <option value="all">Все</option>
    <option value="all">10W40</option>
    <option value="red">5W40</option>
    <option value="blue">5W30</option>
    <option value="green">5W20</option>
    <option value="green">0W30</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="all" class="current">Все</option>
    <option value="all">Бензин</option>
    <option value="red">Дизель</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="all" class="current">Все</option>
    <option value="total">Total</option>
    <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
</select>
```

Если выбрана марка, то применяется фильтр по марки. Если дополнительно выбран тип топлива, то применяется фильтр по марки и по топливу одновременно.

В самом блоке прописаны параметры в атрибуте `class`. Блоки имеют вид:

```html
<div class="all 5W30 benzin disel motul"> </div>
```

Где: `5W30`, `benzin`, `disel`, `motul` - параметры по которым должен отображаться блок.

Все позиции выводятся на одной странице, то есть постраничной навигации нет.

Comment: А что фильтровать-то?

Comment: Идут блоки типа 

<div class="all 5W30 benzin disel motul">

</div>
Где: 5W30, benzin, disel, motul параметры по которым должен отображаться блок

Comment: Сразу всем списком. 29 позиций

Comment: Фильтровать лучше на серверной части...а на клиенте просто показывать готовое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Особенность**: при выборе выпадающего списка, остальные списки перестраиваются, оставляя только доступные варианты.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // `NodeList` из выпадающих списков.
  const SELECTS = document.querySelectorAll('select.linked__data');

  // `NodeList` товаров для фильтрации.
  const LIST = document.querySelectorAll('#result .filtered');

  // Индекс текущего выпадающего списка,
  // в котором было изменено значение пользователем.
  let currentIndex = 0;

  // Функция фильтрации и перерисовки выпадающих списков.
  function filterList(event, index) {
    // Массив классов из выбранных выпадающих списков.
    const query = [];

    // Уникальных значения выбранных классов
    // для обновленного списка.
    // Нужен для перестроения выпадающих списков.
    const filtered = new Set();

    // 1. Меняем индекс текущего выпадающего списка,
    // на котором был произведен выбор пользователем.
    currentIndex = index;

    // 2. Формирование запроса для выбранных значений всех `select`.
    SELECTS.forEach(function(select, index) {
      // Сбрасываем `value`, если `index` больше текущего выбранного.
      if (index > currentIndex) select.value = '';

      // Если в списке выбран пункт, добавляем в запрос.
      if (select.value) query.push(select.value);
    });

    // 3. Фильтруем список товаров, попутно формируя `filtered`.
    LIST.forEach(function(product, index) {
      if (query.every(prop => product.classList.contains(prop))) {
        product.classList.forEach(item => filtered.add(item));
        product.classList.remove('hide');
      } else {
        product.classList.add('hide');
      }
    });

    // 4. По отфильтрованным данным формируем доступные выпадающие списки.
    // Для текущего списка ничего не меняем, поэтому currentIndex + 1,
    // то есть начинаем формирование только со следующего.
    let i = currentIndex + 1;

    for (i; i < SELECTS.length; i++) {
      Array.from(SELECTS[i].options)
        .forEach(function(option) {
          // Если элемент списка не имеет `value` или
          // `value` находится в `filtered`, то покажем его.
          if ('' == option.value || filtered.has(option.value)) {
            option.hidden = '';
          } else {
            option.hidden = 'hidden';
          }
        });
    }
  }

  // Регистрируем обработчика события для каждого выпадающего списка.
  SELECTS.forEach(function(item, index) {
    item.addEventListener('input', (event) => filterList(event, index));
  });
});
```

```css
.filter__section {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 -8px;
}

.form__group {
  width: 25%;
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.form__label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.form__control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.filtered {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.filtered.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h2>Масла моторные</h2>
  <form action="">
    <div class="filter__section">
      <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label">Бренд</label>
        <select name="filter__brand" class="form__control linked__data">
          <option value="">Выбрать ...</option>
          <option value="idemitsu">IDEMITSU</option>
          <option value="toyota">TOYOTA</option>
          <option value="zic">ZIC</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label">Вязкость по SAE</label>
        <select name="filter__viscosity" class="form__control linked__data">
          <option value="">Выбрать ...</option>
          <option value="0w20">0w20</option>
          <option value="0w30">0w30</option>
          <option value="5w30">5w30</option>
          <option value="5w40">5w40</option>
          <option value="10w40">10w40</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label">Тип двигателя</label>
        <select name="filter__engine" class="form__control linked__data">
          <option value="">Выбрать ...</option>
          <option value="petrol">Бензин</option>
          <option value="diesel">Дизель</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form__group">
        <label class="form__label">Объем канистры</label>
        <select name="filter__size" class="form__control linked__data">
          <option value="">Выбрать ...</option>
          <option value="1L">1 л</option>
          <option value="4L">4 л</option>
          <option value="5L">5 л</option>
          <option value="6L">6 л</option>
          <option value="20L">20 л</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="products__section">
    <div id="result" class="products__list">
      <div class="filtered 0w30 idemitsu petrol diesel 4L">IDEMITSU Zepro Touring Pro 0w30 SN/CF/GF-5 синтетическое, универсальное 4л</div>
      <div class="filtered 5w40 idemitsu petrol 1L">IDEMITSU Zepro Racing 5w40 SN синтетическое, для бензинового двигателя 1л</div>

      <div class="filtered 0w20 toyota petrol 5L">Toyota 0w20 SN/GF-5 синтетическое, для бензинового двигателя 5л</div>
      <div class="filtered 0w20 toyota petrol 1L">Toyota 0w20 SN/GF-5 синтетическое, для бензинового двигателя 1л</div>

      <div class="filtered 10w40 zic petrol 6L">ZIC X5 10w40 SM полусинтетическое, для бензинового двигателя 6л</div>
      <div class="filtered 5w30 zic diesel 20L">ZIC X7 5w30 CF/SL синтетическое, для дизельного двигателя 20л</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Так автор указал такой мизерный набор данных, скорее всего, для примера. В реальности будет простыня кода. Это все лучше через запрос на сервер делать.

Comment: @СергейВ., в комментариях к вопросу указаны 29 позиций. Представьте, что есть какая-нибудь станция по замене масла местного значения и таблица в формате HTML. Какой смысл поднимать сервер, писать API?

Comment: 29 так 29... Тогда и джиквери не грешно подклеить, вряд ли там будет посещалка огромная...

Comment: @СергейВ., а смысл? Тут из "некроссбраузерного" только конструкция `Array.from`.

Comment: Подскажите как добавить checkbox со своим параметром фильтрации